# How to plot rainfall on 3 dimensions

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, curated-data

I am currently working on making a 3D plot with latitude on the x, longitude on the y, and total rainfall during hurricane Harvey on the z. My desire is to take historical hurricane data in order to better understand how to allocate resources in the event of another disaster.

I am thinking about going about this problem by using the `WeatherData` function in order to acquire the historical rainfall data from a given weather station and plot coordinates and rainfall height in 3 dimensions.

I am new to the *Mathematica* language. Does anyone have any suggestions or alternative approaches?

Comment: You might get some inspiration here: [Hurricane Matthew and historical tropical storms](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/936765)